# HP laserjet m1132 MFP does not work on ubuntu

Tags: printing

I am having problems with LaserJet m1132 MFP working on Ubuntu 16.04 - the system does not recognize the printer.

I am totally new to Linux in general, so hope someone can help me with this issue.

From what I have gathered hplip connects to hplipopensource.com/ which no longer operates, so I am completely lost from where I could get them elsewhere.

Comment: What does it say exactly, do you have `hplip` installed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes - I have hplip installed. My printer is connected via USB, and when I go to terminal and used hp - setup I receive this error:

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: Failed to connect to HPLIP site. Error code = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui4/queuesconf.py", line 188, in NextButton_clicked
    self.disable_smart_install()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui4/queuesconf.py", line 256, in disable_smart_install
    FailureUI(self, queryString(ERROR_FAILED_TO_DOWNLOAD_FILE, 0, source + ".asc"))

Comment: From what I've gathered hplip site is no longer working, so there is no way to get hp drivers for linux?